# What does "broken lives" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a comment made by a poster in response to [this](http://www.salon.com/2014/05/31/i_never_meant_to_deceive_him_love_and_betrayal_in_the_virtual_world/) article:

> Absolutely correct. Intentionally obscuring who you are and what your desires are may lead to heartache and in rare occurrences **broken lives**. I personally, unlike this articles author never ever want to come close to breaking another individuals life.

What does it mean when your life is broken, or to break someone's life?

Comment: Seems like it's just a somewhat unidiomatic way of saying _ruined lives_ or _destroyed lives_, possibly through a confusion with _broken hearts_. No special, hidden meaning behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "broken lives" is an idiom (and a borderline cliché) referring to human lives shattered, destroyed, or severely damaged by (usually) a personally or communally catastrophic event. The first instance of this phrase that a Google Books search turns up is from *[The Oxford and Cambridge Magazine for 1856](http://books.google.com/books?id=G3gNAQAAMAAJ&q=%22their+broken+lives%22&dq=%22their+broken+lives%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OEvhU7m3KIj7oAS_yYDYBw&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg)* [combined snippets]:

> Travellers in that distant land, going through the mountain-pass and valley where the town lay once, walk down the beach-line, looking at the furious beating of the sea-waves that have not ceased to flow, are blown upon by the same old winds that sang through the pine-forest ages long ago; for those winds, visiting all lands within the upper zone, returning, finding all things changed from when they left the mountain-gorge years before, are still the same. No man now, passing through the valley, thinks ever of the people that dwelt there, happy and brave; thinks ever of their sorrows and their love, nor their **broken lives**, nor noble deaths.

Another early instance is from Joseph Parkinson, "[A Visit to the Royal Hospital for Incurables](http://books.google.com/books?id=8bIHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA10&dq=%22their+broken+lives%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bk_hU9zsEITvoASlvoDQBw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22their%20broken%20lives%22&f=false)," (*Daily News*, May 10, 1869), reprinted in *Three Visits to the Royal Hospital for Incurables, West Hill, Putney Heath* (1870):

> Concerning some charities, doubts may arise as to whether they engender any of the miseries they profess to relieve ; but no such cavilling can arise here.These people have been struck down by an irresistible power, and ask only to spend the remnant of their **broken lives** uncomplainingly and in quiet.

And here is an example that (typical of many early instances of the phrase) develops the image in a religious context. From Edward Hardy, "No Waste," in *Faint Yet Pursuing and Other Sermons* (1888):

> The mistake many make, is trying to gather up the fragments of their **broken lives** in their own strength without thinking of the only One who can enable them to do it.

As this Ngram graph for the years 1860 through 2008 indicates, "broken lives" [the blue line] is actually a more common phrase in published writing than "ruined lives" [the red line] or "destroyed lives" [the green line]—even though it doesn't benefit from matches for instances of *lives* plus the simple past tense (that is, "broke lives"), as "ruined lives" and "destroyed lives" do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It means "interrupted lives"  that is lives whose courses have been dramatically changed by some unforeseen event.

Example: 
[Broken lives](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_Lives):

> Broken Lives was written by Estelle Blackburn between 1992 and 1998. *The book is about the false imprisonment of two people,* John Button and Darryl Beamish *who were both convicted for murders that were later proved to be committed by Eric Cooke the last man hanged in Western Australia in the Fremantle Gaol.*